# I am not sure where to rebase my feature branch from?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, rebase

I created a feature branch (`branch-a`) from a remote branch called `develop`.

Performed some work on it and it sat in PR for a long time so did not get merged back to `develop`.

Whilst waiting for PR I had to do some more work on a new feature related to `branch-a` so created `branch-b` from `branch-a`.

`branch-a` has been merged into develop now but I am not sure how to rebase `branch-b`?

Should i set the upstream on `branch-b` to be `develop` and then rebase:

`git fetch origin && git rebase -i develop`

Or should I rebase `branch-b` against `branch-a` then set up the PR against `develop`?

Comment: Edited with thanks :)

Comment: Can you show what you intend the final commit graph to look like, and what it currently looks like?

Comment: I am not sure how to sorry!  Now `branch-a` is merged I want `branch-b` to be up to date with the latest from `develop` so that when it is time to merge `branch-b` then it will not be out of sync.

Comment: Since `branch-a` has been merged to `develop` you can simply rebase onto `develop`. No need to change upstream: upstream branch is only the remote branch your current branch is linked to, and the upstream is supposed to contain your branch published changes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just bring `branch-b` to be on top of `develop`, since the merger of `branch-a`, then you can just:

```sh
git checkout branch-b
git rebase develop
```

or, as suggested in the comments: `git rebase develop branch-b`

This would just work like any other rebase and bring `b` on top of develop. Keep in mind that you **might** still have conflicts.

*Edit:* one possible thing that could happen, if you have changed the commits, is that you can force this to happen with `git rebase --onto`.

Comment: `git rebase develop branch-b` would do both those steps in a single command.

Comment: done.  there were lots of conflicts! took a while!!!